# How to flash background image on square after document.querySelectorAll('.square')

Tags: javascript

I am working on a whac a mole game where the background image should flash when the square is hit. For example an image that says "hit".
The square has been targeted correctly on function showImage(), tested with a console.log, and called in a forEach loop. I don't know the next step. I know I need to grab css class with background image of square and add an image. Maybe a set timer is involved. I have tried this and cannot get it working. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/jOyRdee)

```
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square')
const mole = document.querySelector('.mole')
const timeLeft = document.querySelector('#time-left')
const score = document.querySelector('#score')

let result = 0
let hitPosition
let currentTime = 60
let timerId = null

function showImage() {
    if ((document.onclick = squares)) {
        squares.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        //console.log('it is working');
    } else {
        alert('it is not working');
    }
}

function randomSquare() {
  squares.forEach(square => {
    square.classList.remove('mole')
  })

  let randomSquare = squares[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)]
  randomSquare.classList.add('mole')

  hitPosition = randomSquare.id
}

squares.forEach(square => {
  square.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    if (square.id == hitPosition) {
      result++
      score.textContent = result
      hitPosition = null
      showImage();
    }
  })
})

function moveMole() {
  timerId = setInterval(randomSquare, 500)
}

moveMole()

function countDown() {
 currentTime--
 timeLeft.textContent = currentTime

 if (currentTime == 0) {
   clearInterval(countDownTimerId)
   clearInterval(timerId)
   alert('GAME OVER! Your final score is ' + result)
 }

}

let countDownTimerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this could handled by a class that displays an image in the background.

```
.bg-img {
  background-image: url('');
}
```

And then in the function showImage() you set the class name `bg-img` on the element:

```
function showImage() {
  squares.classList.add('bg-img');
  setTimeout(function(){
    squares.classList.remove('bg-img');
  }, 1000);
}
```

And remove the class name again 1000 ms after.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. After trying your solution I get "Property of "add" undefined." I remember running into this before. I updated the codepen. To save time I just used a background color instead of an image.

Comment: I meant to say current error is "Cannot read property "add" of undefined."

Comment: @user3531040 OK, I didn't consider what "squares" was, but apparently not an element. Find the element that needs the image in the background and call classList.add() on that.

Comment: You were pretty much right. A friend helped me see I was simply missing square.classList.add('hit'); in the forEach loop and missing the css hit class. Here is an updated codepen https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/dyNEbgp